# PHP, erro ao fazer consulta

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

O meu problema, é que estou querendo fazer uma consulta , mas não estou conseguindo buscar todos os registros, e é isto que não estou conseguindo fazer.
Eu mudarei a SQL mais tarde, então deixei assim para testar. alguém pode me ajudar??

este é o Erro

> AVISO: Mysqli_query() espera o parâmetro 1 para ser mysqli, string
>   data em /home/u777508079/public_html/testeConsultar.php na linha 19

```
 <?php

$hostname_conexao = "************";
$username_conexao = "***********";
$password_conexao = "***********";
$database_conexao = "*************";

$sql3 =  mysqli_connect($hostname_conexao, $username_conexao, $password_conexao, $database_conexao);

//$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];   AND morador.id_pessoa = $matricula
$querybanco = mysqli_query( $sql3, "SELECT placa FROM veiculo,morador WHERE morador.id_pessoa = veiculo.id_pessoa  ");

$dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querybanco);

$placa2 = $dados['placa'];

$link = "SELECT placa FROM veiculo,morador WHERE morador.id_pessoa = veiculo.id_pessoa";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql3)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
        echo $row["placa"];
        echo ",";
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Essas credencias estão certas?

Comment: estão sim! nas outras páginas do programa funciona

Comment: E você vai deixar essa informação no post? Pra qualquer um poder acessar?

Comment: valeu man, nem tinha parado pra pensar =)

Comment: @IgorMatsumoto diferente de fóruns, neste site não há a necessidade de adicionar RESOLVIDO no titulo. Apesar da pergunta estar fechada, você ainda pode aceitar a resposta dada, clicando no `v` à esquerda dela. Visite [tour] para conhecer o funcionamento do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problemas é que seus parâmetros estão invertidos, altere da seguinte forma:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($sql3, $link)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: ValeuMan !! Deu certo

Comment: Ótimo, considere marcar a resposta como correta caso tenha ajudado! =)

Comment: ixi, eu pensei ter alterado no titulo, bom, valeu por avisar (y)